# Set F7/F8/F9 to perform iTunes functions like built-in keyboard

Tags: macos, itunes, keyboard

I have a non-Apple keyboard connected to my MacBook Pro. Is there a way to make the <kbd>F7</kbd> <kbd>F8</kbd> and <kbd>F9</kbd> do the previous song / play-pause / next song actions like they do on the built-in keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

[CoverSutra](http://sophiestication.com/coversutra/), among other things, will let you set your shortcuts the way you want it

> ### Global Shortcuts
>
> Instantly control iTunes from anywhere, quickly and easily. Play, pause, rate, show, skip, rewind, fast forward... and much more! CoverSutra gives you complete control over your music with fully customizable keyboard shortcuts.

[image: CoverSutra shortcut preferences]

It's main feature (at least for me) is its Music Search. Its like Spotlight for iTunes. Activate it with a keyboard shortcut and search away!

[image]

Comment: I'm sure this works, but isn't there a simpler solution? I really just want the keyboard shortcut if possible...